# How to use Ethernet connection to provide Internet to a router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

What I want to achieve is to share an Ethernet-based Internet connection using ONLY a router to some computers and wireless devices.

At the moment, I have a RJ45 cable that provides me Internet (it's from the building where I live) and I'm planning to buy a router. Is a router capable to achieve what I want? If so, what particular feature (if any) should it have to do that? What is the standard procedure to get it?

Thanks for your answers!

P.S.: I tried to search this on Super User but I didn't found anything that would match this situation. But, I'm not a native English speaker, so I could have done it with wrong words. I apologize if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, this is exactly what a router is for: Have one Internet connection that comes in through RJ-45 Ethernet cable and split it to multiple computers while in the process create a unique network.

You plug in the RJ-45 cable into the WAN port, and you plugin all the devices in the LAN ports and connect wireless clients to its wifi capabilities.

Once you setup the router, everything will work as expected.

Do note, if you need to open ports, you do so on that router, but you probably also have to ask your landlord to open ports on their router. For simple internet usage you don't need to worry about ports. Only for special programs such as torrent, gaming, hosting servers, etc, do you really need port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed just hook up most off-the-shelf routers to your Ethernet cable to allow multiple PCs to share that one connection. What you are looking for is NAT (Network Address Translation), which allows you to use your one Internet IP address for multiple machines on the internal side of your router. Note that if the cable you are connecting to is already NATed, you may not be able to reach back to your machines from the internet however, you would need to be able to setup port forwards to access the inside of your router from the internet, but for most stuff like surfing the web, this won't be needed.